# Embed YouTube Live Stream on Android

Tags: android, api, youtube, live

Question: Is it possible to embed a youtube livestream to android? I used the youtube API and then YouTubeStandalonePlayer

```
 public static final String YouTube_API = "youtubeapiexample";
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "8fo9y0CsCjo";

startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(MainActivity.this,
                            YouTube_API, VIDEO_ID, 0, true, true));
```

that is my code for uploaded videos on youtube and it works on uploaded videos. but I tried to put the embed code of the livestream but it didn't work. Is there a right way or am i only doing my code wrong?

Comment: Make sure your application is registered in your developer console.

Answer (score 0):

`Youtube`'s live streaming API's code sample for Java is available [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/) . The code is well documented and explains API's `liveStreams.list` method to retrieve a list of video stream settings that a channel can use to broadcast live events on YouTube.